# Google Sign In / 0auth / Security

Tags: javascript, html, security, google-signin

I used
[google's 0auth sign in API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)
on my website. 
This involves setting up a project and client ID where I specified my website URL as an authorized JavaScript origin.
To activate on my website, the client ID is included in the meta tag:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

As I understand it, I can only integrate this sign in with a webpage on my domain - the clientID is useless on its own.

What, if any, security considerations are of concern when using this service? Should I consider trying to mask the clientID so it doesn't appear on my website source (not sure how I would do that yet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that the client ID has any security implications, so there is no need to try to protect it.

In some cases, there is a client credentials which do need protection.  But if you have a JavaScript client, then most likely you are using implicit grant type, which does not use these credentials (because the client is not able to protect it).

There is a [section on client identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-3.7) in the Oauth threat model.  As you can see, they do not specify the need to protect the identifier in any way.  This gives pretty good assurance that you do not need to try outrageous stunts to protect it.

For further evidence, read [Aaron Parecki's Oauth Simplified](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/), where he writes:

> After registering your app, you will receive a client ID and a client secret. The client ID is considered public information, and is used to build login URLs, or included in Javascript source code on a page.